# How can I http-authentication login with javascript for an iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe, http-authentication

I need to make a page that will

1. Login to a site automatically via http-authentication
2. Show said site with an iframe

I was thinking I could use XHR and specify the login headers directly, and then use javascript to create the iframe.  Does this make sense?  Will it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Due to the same-origin-policy your XHR approach won't work.

However, for HTTP authentication you can simply include the data in the url, i.e. the `src` of the `<iframe>`:

```
<iframe src="http://username:password@domain.tld/..."></iframe>
```

I think I don't have to mention that this should not be done if the login credentials are sensitive - they are likely to show up in the browser history.

Comment: I guess I need to add a new question somewhere on how to make this work in ie, since it (unlike chrome and firefox) seems to disable the iframe (presumably for security reasons?)

Comment: this is not working in 2019 due to security, what is alternative ?