# How can I make pre-authenticated iframes work in IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, iframe, internet-explorer-8, http-authentication

In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11439927/how-can-i-http-authentication-login-with-javascript-for-an-iframe) I asked how to make iframes preauthenticate http auth.  It turns out I already had the answer, but it seems to have stopped working in IE 8 or 9.  Here's my stripped down iframe that works perfectly in chrome and firefox:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" >
  <head>
    <title>yay.</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe width="800" height="800" src="http://user:pass@10.6.1.99"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm guessing it must be some esoteric new IE security setting to make this work.  Can anyone tell me how to set it to make this code work?

Comment: What does the `iframe`'s HTTP request look like? Do you get a `401 Unauthorized` response? [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) can help you debug on older IE's.

Comment: According to fiddler IE never even makes a request if you include the auth stuff.  If you elide the auth stuff it makes a request that gets a 401 and then prompts the user.